# typescript error 2532 with object square brackets access

Tags: typescript, object, enums

I got the `ts error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)`  error when I attempt to check the value of a field inside an object, where the key of the object can be a value of an Enum.

Here is a small example to reproduce this issue:

```js
enum Fruits {
   Apple = "Apple",
   Bannana = "Bannana",
   // and a lot more…
}

type fruitsInfo = {
  [key in Fruits]? : { cal: number, carb: number, }
};

type numberOfFruits = {
  [key in Fruits]? : number
};

function makeMeal(info : fruitsInfo, fruits : numberOfFruits) {
   for (const keyStr in info) {
      const key = keyStr as Fruits;
      if (fruits[key] > 2) {
         console.log("You eat a lot!")
      }
   }
}
```

[Run on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFwM5QN4FgBQV8CCADkQDbBQC8UARMWcDQDS75QBCAhiCN51bS48+zVvgD04qNwAm0qKQD2yKBEVxggMgJcAX1y5kATyIUAZghSoAkiFOKB2PFADaAa2CGoiELAtoAugD8UABcmFAAxpykYeAQAEbAcEyRnHDxsZCJyVB6ODoA3Po4RiZQcdkA8qbwSGgOYm4eXj61lkGh5VlJukU4uKZgIBHIiIo+EJzuALLA0QAU3nad5nXWtoopq5adFUnVbWgAlJhiUHZwUPMR46gq7oYAysiX3i12J45sbDcgd1APAQPZ6XTjoQ6oPrffCIUxXbZoJqGfxQAB8UAATJ8ztDIrdFOQAHRKADm8xoAE1FGAoHMVPwlMgAIQ0I44-B5Nh5HRAA).

Of course this is an example, my code is quite more complicated. I cannot change the structure of `fruitsInfo`  nor `numberOfFruits`  by removing the `?`, because the fact is, the object may not contain everything.

The one thing I know for sure is: I am sure that if a key is in `info`, it is in `fruits`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is literally `Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)`

So you basically have

```
      if (undefined > 2) { // <! The value 'undefined' cannot be used here.(18050)
         console.log("You eat a lot!")
      }
```

You need to either refine `undefined` to `NonNullable` via `!` clause or to `number`

```
      if (fruits[key]! > 2) { // say that it's not `undefined`
         console.log("You eat a lot!")
      }      
      if (Number(fruits[key]) > 2) { // convert it to number (NaN)
         console.log("You eat a lot!")
      }
```

Comment: Thank you ! I had tried to put the `!` before the brackets, because in the object notation it is before `myObject?.key`. This works perfectly 